# Trying to Compile MMC into mex file using cygwin64

Tags: cygwin, mex

I try to follow all the instructions on this particular page:

http://mcx.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/index.cgi?MMC/CompileLog/2016.1

But I get back a huge error stack:

[It doesn't work!!!!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Hds.png)

Can anyone instruct me how this type of compiling works and how I can successfully compile the mmc program.

Comment: `doesn't work` is a bit vague. Are you using `make CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` ? Please note the instructions are making a bit of confusion between gcc and x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc; the first is for cygwin program the second for windows program. It seems you need the second.

Comment: Hi matzeri! So I installed the cygwin64 gcc and make ust like it says on the site. The MMC source code can be found at https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcx/files/mmc/ but the src comes into a single package. I use Cygwin64 terminal and cd my way into the src folder containing the header and c files. I use  make CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc to compile the mmc and  that seems to work, as there is an mmc executable in bin. However, I do not know where to put mexopts.bat and when I run make mex CC=g++, I get the errors in tthe link It Doesn't work!

Comment: Which version ? on  mmc-2016.5-src.tar.gz there is no mexopts.bat. Anyway it can not work with `make mex CC=g++` eventually it could work with `make mex CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` as you need a C++ compiler compatible with the previos C Compiler. Question: do you have Matlab installed ?

Comment: Yes I do. Version 2015b is currently installed o my computer.

Comment: have you tried `make mex CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` ?

Comment: I have and I getr back this delightful error message: make: *** [../comons/MakeFile_common.mk:165: bin/mmc] ERror 127